# Using EventStore in a CQRS "architecture" makes unnecessary the use of a message bus?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture, cqrs, eventstoredb

I'm pretty new to the paradigms and associated architectures such as CQRS. I started a project where I think this type of technology fits. I found it interesting use EventStore in the project, but I read a bit in the documentation and I see that the use of EventStore makes it unnecessary to have a message bus, as the EventStore itself allows the subscription to events - is this correct? Would I have some advantage in implementing a bus on the top of EventStore?

Comment: changed tag from event-store (NES) to get-event-store (GES) - assuming you mean http://geteventstore.com Also I'd suggest you talk a bit more about the business function of your system as a whole and/or consider going to the ddd-cqrs-es  or eventstore mailing lists

Comment: This question doesn't really have an answer other than "compare the features provided by GES and whatever service bus you are considering". As @RubenBartelink mentions, you should detail your business functions.

Comment: @dotnetguy : Thank you  very mucho for your grammar fix.

Answer (score 7):

Message bus and event store are two different things that serve two different purposes.

The EventStore (GES) allows subscribing to events by using subscriptions, either client-tracked or server-tracked (competing consumers), plus long polling of ATOM feeds. Events organised into streams and each stream havign its own name, contains events for this stream. As CQRS and EventSourcing usually applied for DDD projects, streams are usually represent aggregates and reading individual streams allow re-creating the aggregate state and reading events from a stream category (aggregate type) is used for projections (building read models). Each subscriber control its own process of reading events and since events are stored, you can read them as many times as you want.

Message bus has nothing to do with saving events. It targets on reliably delivering messages between endpoints. Message bus usually supports broker or federated topology and different patterns like direct send, publish-subscribe and request-response. Once a message consumers ACKs the message, it is removed from the queue and cannot be read again. If you have no subscriber for messages that are getting published, you lose them forever.

Meaning, both are useful patterns but event store is used more for persistence and message bus / broker for durable queues and reliable delivery.

Answer (score 4):

I tend to think of it like this, and this is how we have it set up:

Message Bus: Handling of command and event brokering. This used to communicate between various services and to broadcast events. "Event" in this context is transient. It's just there for subscribers to trigger off of.

EventStore: This is for the storing of actions taken against a domain entity. "Event" in this context is persistent. It exists to replay and gain 'state' for an object.

You can't replay transient messages because they only fire once and then they are consumed. Events in the EventStore are persistent/replayable and are replayed to gain an objects state or to build a projection. One is a broker, the other is a source.

Keep a thick line drawn between the two physically and conceptually.

Answer (score 3):

> I see the use of EventStore makes unnecessary having a message bus <snip>... is this correct?

Yes, using an event store can make a message bus unnecessary. An event store is a persistent queue where you can either read the events directly and in the case of GES you can also subscribe to events as they happen. Apart from GES, in other event stores, you can resort to database polling to get new messages out of process from the database. (Periodically send the request for "all messages since X".)

One of the primary differences between a message bus and an event store is that subscriptions will be "pull" instead of "push". A message bus does "push" where it decides what you have seen and what you still need. Event stores that I have seen use a "pull" model (for out of process) where you keep track of your own checkpoint. There is some minor accounting to that (periodically saving your checkpoint), but there's also a lot of power as you will see below.

*Note: GES does have a push model, but it's for producer/consumer scenarios, not delivering the same message to multiple endpoints.*

Another difference is that you cannot usually tell an event bus to send you all the messages starting with X. Even if it has that feature, depending on how long ago X was, it may no longer have those messages. So if you discover a bug in your code, you may have to resort to [ETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) from one system to another to fix it. Bugs invariably happen, so you end up having two different processes for propagating data, one based on events for the happy path, and one based on ETL for data fixes.

But with an event store, you can use the same process for happy path and data fixes. All events still exist (by default, unless configured otherwise) and with the pull model you are in control of what messages you want to see. So given the same bug, you can fix the code, then blank out the affected read model, set its checkpoint to zero, and it will rebuild from scratch when it restarts. No need to also develop an ETL process. (Ops concern: If your event store is large, a rebuild could take some time, but you can create an initial rebuild side by side with the old model and just swap it over in the maintenance window.)

Some good info/experience with that can be found [here](https://tech.jet.com/blog/2016/09-07-event-sourcing-awesome/).

A bus still makes sense in other scenarios... for example when only the latest messages matter. Or when there are just too many messages to feasibly store.

> Would have some advantage to implement the use of a bus in the top to EventStore?

I would not think so. The topology that could make sense for this case is to have some code subscribe to the event store and publish the new messages to a bus to update many listeners (e.g. for scaling out reads). However, this scenario would be better addressed by using GES-specific features. Namely, the HTTP API using AtomPub and caching proxies. Since events are immutable, after they are seen once, they can be indefinitely cached at every level. This should avoid ever needing to hit the event store except for the first time a message is published. This still allows the client to retain control of its own subscription as well.

Comment: This is the answer.